# Are all functions actually methods in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am confused. Every function that is ever called in Javascript is called by some object. If I invoke it like this: `b();` then this means that my global object invoked it: `global.b();`. So, all of them are methods, right? Why do we call them functions then?

Comment: `(() => { function no(){}; no(); })();` also a method is a function aswell.

Comment: "*If I invoke it like this: `b();` then this means that my global object invoked it: `global.b();`*" - actually, no. It's more like `undefined.b()`, invoked with no `this` value. It's just when `b` is a sloppy-mode function, an `undefined` `this` value becomes the global object.

Comment: Also, there are arrow functions which don't even have a dynamic `this` keyword, they are definitely no methods.

Comment: @Bergi Can you elaborate a little bit more on what you mean by "sloppy-mode function"?

Comment: @Vlada https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 2):

Because a method is a function.

Function definition:

```
A "subroutine" that returns a value
```

Method definiton:

```
A callable member of a object
=> A function of a object
```

So you could say:

```
class Method extends Function
```

In Javascript every function returns a value, if it doesn't it returns undefined. Which makes it return something.

But the real answer is: Does it even matter? I'm going to cite the resource from the software engineering stack: "The point is, none of this is really consistent. It simply reflects the terminology employed by whatever languages are en vogue at the time."

Resources: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/20948/258140